# What is the difference between Register Addressing mode and Direct Addressing mode(8051)?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, embedded, 8051, addressing

I find that there is no difference between the Register Addressing mode and the Direct Addressing mode.
Can anyone tell the difference with respect to the 8051 microcontroller ?

Comment: Try to put an example for each, so that it's clear to everyone what are these two address modes with reference to 8051.

Answer (score 2):

It *could* be confusing since the 8051 has memory mapped registers. So each register is also accessible at a memory address. In fact the 8051 registers simply *are* memory cells, with shortcuts.

However the difference is huge:

- Register addressing point directly to a register. No memory address involved. You say R5, you go straight to R5
- Direct addressing point to a RAM address (only the 256 byte internal one, not XRAM). You say cell 42h, you go to cell 42h

The confusion happens because you can say 'write to cell 05h'. And you are actually writing to R5 (in register bank 0). This characteristic is in fact extremely useful because the 8051 can't transfer directly between two register, but only between a register and a memory cell.